# Optimize this path location script?

Tags: php, optimization, linux

Example Script is located in /home/insp/public_html/deploy/

I want to return the /home/insp/ section

```
$path = realpath(__DIR__);

        $parts = explode('/', $path);

        $newPath = array(
            $parts[0],
            $parts[1],
            $parts[2],
        );

        $realPath = implode('/', $newPath);
```

Is there a better/more effeicent way to acheve this?

Comment: So you want the home directory of the user?

Comment: Yes @Bobby i did see that i could use a simple regex .*public_

Comment: What's stopping you from using `$_SERVER['HOME']` or `getenv('HOME')`?

Comment: That isnt an env variable in cPanel closest i get is     [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/insp/public_html

Comment: But if I read [this documentation](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/ExpVarRef) and [this one](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/CpanelPhp) correctly, you should be able to use `<cpanel print="$homedir">` to get the home directory.

Comment: @Bobby That would work but its not something i want to expose to the public. Thanks for the idea i had no idea that was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up going with this approach:

```
preg_match('/(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*){2}/', realpath(__DIR__), $homeDir);
$homeDir = $homeDir[0];
```

Reason being this is a much stricter regex and will only match valid cPanel usernames in paths which per their docs can only contain alphanumeric characters. This also prevents the need to expose this path to the public as was recommended by another person here.

Comment: You should add some information on why you chose this alternative. As your answer stands at the moment, it does not indicate why this answer is good or recommended.

Comment: @rolfl you're right i've updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

A different way:

```
preg_match(':^/[^/]*/[^/]*/:', realpath(__DIR__), $matches);
$realPath = $matches[0];
```

This matches the first and second files in path, and stores them in $matches.

Comment: I thought about that or doing '.*public_' to get /home/insp/public_ if that's the best way i'll go with it im just farming for opinions. or this (\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*.){3} the issue with the first is it will cause issues if tehre happens to be a folder called public_ anything

Comment: Also your regex does not match anything http://regexr.com?37ir1

Comment: preg_match has a slightly different syntax; removing the colons will work on regexr.com :)